# How to use ScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, scrollviewer

I hope this isn't a duplicate but I can't find any documentation or examples on how to actually *use* `ScrollToVerticalOffset()`. I'm using it in a Windows Phone 8 app, but I think it will still apply to WP7 and Silverlight (although, feel free to correct me if I'm wrong).

So here is my basic set up (pseudo-code from memory):

```
<phone.PivotItem>
   <ScrollViewer>
      <Grid Height="1500">
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!-- about 20 rows, all auto-height -->
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>

         <Border Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBox x:Name="txt1" />
         </Border>
         <Border Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBox x:Name="txt2" />
         </Border>

         <!-- ...... -->

         <Border Grid.Row="19">
            <TextBox x:Name="txt20" />
         </Border>
      </Grid>
   </ScrollViewer>
</phone.PivotItem>
```

So as you can see, I've got a `ScrollViewer` within a `PivotItem`, and inside is a `Grid`. In the `Grid` there are about 20 `TextBox`s, each within a `Border`. I am dynamically setting focus to one of these `TextBox`s when this page loads, so anytime I set focus to `TextBox` #6-20 (roughly) - I have to manually scroll down to see it. I want to auto-scroll my `ScrollViewer` so that whichever `TextBox` has focus, it will be centered for the user to see.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltoverticaloffset%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for `ScrollToVerticalOffset()` says:

> Scrolls the content that is within the ScrollViewer to the specified
>   vertical offset position.

And that it accepts a type of `System.Double`.

What I don't understand is A) the value I'm supposed to pass, and B) how I could even get that value? Is it supposed to be a number between 0 and the height of my `Grid` (1500)? If so, how could I determine the position of any given `TextBox` so I can scroll to it?

If there are any straightforward examples, please feel free to link out to them. I'm not sure if the content within the `ScrollViewer` matters when calling this method, but in case it does I wanted to show exactly how I'm using it.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Small question, why have you implemented this setup? Any reason why not to use the longlistselector? I was wondering about it :)

Comment: Good question - I suppose the main reason is that I wasn't familiar with `LongListSelector`, and I haven't done enough research to know if it would be a better option or not. Basically, I'm making a "top ten leaderboard" type thing which will display the top ten names & scores. If a new score is > than the 10th score, I'll insert a `TextBox` into the correct position and let the user save it. My pseudo-code above obviously doesn't reflect all of this functionality though.

Comment: So in my actual scenario, there are 10 different `TextBlocks` that I'm using as labels, and then they get adjusted/shifted for the "new entry" and a `TextBox` is put in it's place to let the user save their name into that position.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can see any UIElement's position relative to another UIElement using the **UIElement.TransformToVisual** call.

First, get the transform between the TextBox and ScrollViewer.

```
GeneralTransform transform = textBox.TransformToVisual(scrollViewer);
```

Then, figure out what point (0,0) of the TextBox is relative to the ScrollViewer. Meaning, the TextBox origin (0,0) is located at what ScrollViewer position.

```
Point textBoxPosition = transform.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```

Now that you know the Y position of the TextBox relative to the ScrollViewer, scroll to that Y offset.

```
scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(textBoxPosition.Y);
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old post, but the meaning of `VerticalOffset` varies.
Most of the solutions I have seen assume `VeritcalOffset` is in pixels. This is not always the case.

From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.extentheight

If `CanContentScroll` is true, the values of the `ExtentHeight`, `ScrollableHeight`,
`ViewportHeight`, and `VerticalOffset` properties are **number of items**. If
`CanContentScroll` is `false`, the values of these properties are Device Independent Pixels.