# How to make screen scroll when keyboard comes up?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I want to make my screen scroll when virtual keyboard comes so that i can enter text in text boxes hidden behind the keyboard.
In windows phone 8 there is no way of knowing keyboards height.

when i tap text box 1 keyboard pops up, now i want to enter text in text box 4 and 5 by scrolling the screen and without removing the keyboard.

following is the xaml code.

```
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <TextBox x:Name="txt1" ></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="txt2" ></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="txt3" ></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="txt4" ></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="txt5" ></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="txt6" ></TextBox>




    </StackPanel>


</Grid>
```

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfLSF.png)

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hos7p.png)

Comment: Could you clarify your question a bit and post some of your XAML code?  It's not exactly clear what you are trying to do.  Are you using C#?  WinRT or Silverlight?

Comment: Which emulator are you using?  In the emulator 8.1, when clicking text box 1, and then text box 4, then text box 5, and then text box 6, the screen scrolls automatically to show the next text box and allow it to be clicked, without closing the virtual keyboard.

Comment: @theMaxx is there a way to scroll the screen so that i can reach textbox 5 without clicking textbox 4, for example you can see adding contact in wp emulator. thanks

Comment: Now I understand what you mean.  You should be able to scroll through the entire app page from top to bottom after the virtual keyboard is displayed, but only part of the app page can be scrolled to.  I would like to know the answer too.  I tried playing around with it for a while but couldn't get it.  I see what you mean by how it works in the People app.

Comment: @theMaxx hey, i found the answer please open the link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474298/when-keyboard-is-show-scrolling-is-limited?