# can the scrollviewer in windows phone be scrolled programmatically?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Is it possible to scroll the `ScrollViewer` from the code?

If YES how?

If NO can you suggest some workaround to get similar effect. I have a ScrollViewer which contains a RichTextBox, I want to scroll the contents from the code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use ScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114991/how-to-use-scrollviewer-scrolltoverticaloffset)

Answer (score 0):

`ScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticallOffset()` scrolls immediately to provided offset

If you need some smooth scrolling with easy functions, first of all create class that allows bindings to `ScrollViewer`:

```
public class ScrollViewerOffsetMediator : FrameworkElement
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ScrollViewer instance to forward Offset changes on to.
    /// </summary>
    public ScrollViewer ScrollViewer
    {
        get { return (ScrollViewer)GetValue(ScrollViewerProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ScrollViewerProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollViewerProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ScrollViewer",
            typeof(ScrollViewer),
            typeof(ScrollViewerOffsetMediator),
            new PropertyMetadata(OnScrollViewerChanged));
    private static void OnScrollViewerChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var mediator = (ScrollViewerOffsetMediator)o;
        var scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)(e.NewValue);
        if (null != scrollViewer)
        {
            scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(mediator.VerticalOffset);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// VerticalOffset property to forward to the ScrollViewer.
    /// </summary>
    public double VerticalOffset
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(VerticalOffsetProperty); }
        set { SetValue(VerticalOffsetProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty VerticalOffsetProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "VerticalOffset",
            typeof(double),
            typeof(ScrollViewerOffsetMediator),
            new PropertyMetadata(OnVerticalOffsetChanged));
    public static void OnVerticalOffsetChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var mediator = (ScrollViewerOffsetMediator)o;
        if (null != mediator.ScrollViewer)
        {
            mediator.ScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset((double)(e.NewValue));
        }
    }
}
```

Than add to xaml:

```
<my:ScrollViewerOffsetMediator x:Name="Mediator" ScrollViewer="{Binding ElementName=SmoothScroll}" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

, where `SmoothScroll` is `ScrollViewer` object.

At this stage you can create any animation you need on `Mediator` object to animate scrolling