# Jumping between marked points (bookmarks) on a single pivot via button clicks

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I was wondering if there's an easy way to jump between different marked points in a single pivot by clicking on buttons with event handlers? Basically the equivalent of links to bookmarks on a web page. For example, I'm at the top of the pivot and click on a button that scrolls me down to the bottom of the pivot.

Thanks,

Bardi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think will be help => [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114991/how-to-use-scrollviewer-scrolltoverticaloffset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114991/how-to-use-scrollviewer-scrolltoverticaloffset)

Another thing, you can create fake(bookmarks) item and use scrollIntoView(item).