# Scroll automatically to a control inside scrollviewer

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1

I have a scrollviewer in page which shows data vertically, and it contains controls like grid, stackpanel and listbox.
Listbox contains items with expanderview. On click of expander view header it expands, I just want that whenever it expands its content get visible in page. Means i have to automatically change scroll position and make visible a Listbox selected control.

Is there any way?

Comment: What's the condition to scroll to the object? Do all the nested elements remain the same size? .....and most importantly, what have you tried?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have added more details to my question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to manage it Programatically with use of `Timer`. When the timer is triggerd, we call the `timer_Tick` event handler, which scrolls to the current index and marks it as selected, and then updates the index. After the last item is highlighted the index is reset to the first item. You can find useful sample here [Auto-scrolling ListBox for Windows Phone](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Auto-scrolling_ListBox_for_Windows_Phone)

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the `offset` where you want to scroll to, and then use [ScrollToVerticalOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltoverticaloffset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)(your_offset_value) method.

Have a look over here : [How to use ScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114991/)