# ScrollViewer scroll to specific control

Tags: windows-phone-8, scrollviewer

I have a scrollviewer with an item template on it.  the user sends a control number and I need to scroll to that item.  How can I find the offset for the scrollviewer?

here is the scrollviewer that I am using

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" x:Name="ScrollPanel" Padding="0">
    <Grid x:Name="TestPanel" >
        <ItemsControl x:Name="MainItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding PostList}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="PostPanel" Margin="0,5,0,5">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="60" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image x:Name="IconUrl" Source="{Binding IconUrl}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="12,0,12,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="50"/>
                            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="PostAuthorName" Text="{Binding PostAuthorName}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="12,0,12,0" Foreground="Black" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="PostTime" Text="{Binding PostTime}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="12,0,12,0" Foreground="Black" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="ReplyNumber" Text="{Binding ReplyNumber}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Foreground="Black" Margin="12,0,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <RichTextBox x:Name="PostContent" localcontrols:Properties.BBCode="{Binding PostContent}" />
                        <Rectangle Grid.Row="1"  Fill="Gray" Height="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,10,0,10"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: which version of Windows Phone? it matters so you should mention that- with the right tag.

Comment: Thanks, its windows phone 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The offset can be calculated in this way. The code is adopted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15116751/815938).

```
void ScrollToIndex(int index)
{
    var itemContainer = MainItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index) as UIElement;
    GeneralTransform transform = itemContainer.TransformToVisual(ScrollPanel);
    Point position = transform.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
    ScrollPanel.ScrollToVerticalOffset(position.Y);
}
```

Comment: I am trying this technique, however I get null returned for the itemContainer.  item does return correctly though.

Comment: Ok, I got this to work but I had to add UpdateLayout() before the 2nd line to make it work.  It also worked if I did
 var itemContainer = MainItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
instead of the first line
Only problem I have left is other stuff is still updating on the page and as this is run so the content above gets longer and the item I wanted in view is pushed off the bottom.  I am sure that I just need to make sure it is run after everything is loaded.

Comment: @PCur glad that you made it. I will debug the code from your feedback and update my answer when I am on my computer.

Comment: hi @PCur, I have updated my answer. `ContainerFromIndex` is better since the index is provided, and another modification is the return value of `ContainerFromIndex` is cast into a UIElement instead of a FrameworkElement.

Comment: Thanks!  it works great.  As you can see from my original post, I use a local property called BBCode to set the RichTextBox.  Its based on bbcode returned from a website and it sets the font, pictures etc.  do you know if there is a way to hold the control in view while stuff above it loads?

Answer (score 0):

The ItemsControl does not implement logic that allows scrolling to a particular item. You can use the ListBox control instead. This control has a ScrollIntoView method that accepts the object you would like to scroll to as an argument. You can still use the RadWrapPanel by setting the ItemsPanel property of the ListBox control.

You don't have properties, but you have two methods for this: ScrollToVerticalOffset (to scroll vertically) and ScrollToHorizontalOffset (to scroll horizontally).

```
this.scrollViewer2.ScrollToVerticalOffset(0);
```