# Windows Phone Scroll to Element

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I have a windows phone 8.1 page includes a hidden user control.
When user press on a button on the page, user control becomes visible at the bottom of the page but it becomes still invisible user, there I need to scroll into element.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You might want to peek here once: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114991/how-to-use-scrollviewer-scrolltoverticaloffset

Comment: @bit My app is not silverlight based. Windows phone 8.1 store app.